# How can I calculate the number of categorical occurrences in one dataframe and map to another?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Thank you for any help you can provide.

I have two dataframes:

```
df1
+-----+----------+
| key | category |
+-----+----------+
|   1 | B        |
|   1 | A        |
|   1 | A        |
|   2 | C        |
|   2 | B        |
|   3 | C        |
|   3 | B        |
|   3 | C        |
|   4 | B        |
|   4 | B        |
+-----+----------+

df2
+-----+----------+
| key | is_thing |
+-----+----------+
|   1 | yes      |
|   2 | yes      |
|   3 | yes      |
|   4 | no       |
+-----+----------+
```

I need to calculate the number of times each category appears in `df1`, per key, and map the category with the highest sum per key to `df2`, such that categories without majorities result in `NaN` and the desired output is:

```
+-----+----------+----------+
| key | is_thing | category |
+-----+----------+----------+
|   1 | yes      | A        |
|   2 | yes      | NaN|
|   3 | yes      | C        |
|   4 | no       | B        |
+-----+----------+----------+
```

How can I do this using Python and pandas? Reproducible program below:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'key': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4], 
         'category': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B']}
data2 = {'key': [1, 2, 3, 4], 
         'is_thing': ['yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'no']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

data_desired = {'key': [1, 2, 3, 4], 
                'is_thing': ['yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'no'],
                'cotegory': ['A', 'null', 'C', 'B']}

df_desired = pd.DataFrame(data_desired)
```

Deeply appreciate any assistance provided. Thank you.

Comment: can  a key have 2 category with same max count?

Comment: @anky_91 Thanks, yes it can, in which case the desired output would be null

Comment: are we missing the `observation` column?

Comment: @ksooklall Thank you, I see that my language is unclear, I mean to say the number of times each category appears in df1, per key. Edited for clarity.

Comment: Why `null` instead of the Pandas standard, `NaN`?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Thank you, it's immaterial, NaN is good.

Comment: @TuckDrace It might be worth editing the post, and letting the answerers (?) know. Immaterial is the coolest word to use instead of "missing data", I'll remember that ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df2['category']=df2['key'].map(

  df1.groupby('key')
     .category
     .value_counts()
     .groupby(level=0)
     .filter(lambda x: x.nunique() == len(x)) 
     .unstack()
     .idxmax(1)
)
print(df2)

   key is_thing category
0    1      yes        A
1    2      yes      NaN
2    3      yes        C
3    4       no        B
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way of doing this using [`crosstab()`](https://www.google.com/search?q=pd+crosstab&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN822IN823&oq=pd+crosstab&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.2200j1j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```
m=pd.crosstab(df1['key'],df1['category'])
cond=m.isin(m.max(1)).sum(1)
```

---

```
d=dict(zip(m.index,np.where(cond.eq(1),m.idxmax(1),np.nan)))
df2['category']=df2['key'].map(d)
#df_desired=df2.assign(category=df2['key'].map(d)) for a new df keeping df2 same
print(df2)
```

---

```
   key is_thing category
0    1      yes        A
1    2      yes      NaN
2    3      yes        C
3    4       no        B
```

Answer (score 3):

```
new_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'left', left_on='key', right_on='key')

new_df.groupby(['key', 'is_thing'])['category'].agg(lambda s: s.mode()).map(lambda x: x if np.isscalar(x) else None)

>>> output  #  the index is (key, is_thing) (so reset it if you want).

1   yes A
2   yes 
3   yes C
4   no  B
```

Comment: What would be the other possible values for `x` in that apply (which could be made into a map, by the way)?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, ah true. It can be a map